# How to enable macros on an external hard-drive

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have an external hard-drive that I have mapped locally to the `e:\` drive. There is a subfolder that contains Excel sheets with macros that I am unable to run.

In `File->Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings` I have already checked `Allow Trusted Locations on my network (not recommended)` and then tried to `Add new location`. Clicking this `Add new location` button brings up a dialog where I can enter the path (such as `e:\mySubfolder`). Yet, when I click `OK` I get this error message:

> The path you have entered cannot be used as a Trusted Location for security reasons. Choose another location or a specific folder.

Of course, I don't want to choose another location since my Excels are on the hard-drive. So, is there something else I can do about it?

Comment: Have you checked if you can trick/bypass it by adding the Trusted Location directly to the registry, eg `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations`?

Comment: That or set a junction point for it on C:

Comment: @JeremyThompson I can add a path into the registry - and the path will be shown in Excel's *Trusted Locations* dialog, however it is greyed and without noticable effect on the behaviour.

Comment: @Raystafarian if you suggest `mklink /j c:\hd e:\mySubfolder` this won't work, as cmd.exe tells me I can only perform them on local volumes.

Comment: What OS? What version excel?

Comment: Try adding it using the full path (not the mapped drive): `\\server\topFolder\mySubfolder`

Answer (score 0):

Besides version of excel & os, if you are in a domain can cause this issue.

Make a folder on your E:\ drive called Spot or any other name you want.
go to the trusted locations, you should see several already in there.

click browse with the include sub folder box checked
go to your E:\Spot and add it 
(* Some security policies prevent root access such as E:\ )

if this fails,
close excel, right click and open excel with "run as admin" selected.
Go through and see if can add trusted location